# JavaFX: ComboBox - conflict setButtonCell & setPromptText

Tags: javafx, combobox

I'm using a JFoenix library and I have a problem with ComboBox.

When I want to setPromtText and setButtonCell - the text duplicates.
I want to change the size of font on ButtonCell.

Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private JFXComboBox versionList;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    versionList.setPromptText("<");
    versionList.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String version, boolean empty) {
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(version);
                setFont(Font.font(15));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And as the result I get this:

[image]

Or if promt text "Select":

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted to call the superclass implementation of `updateItem(...)` in your overridden `updateItem(...)` method. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) this will prevent the `item` and `empty` properties from being set; so I suspect that what is happening is that the cell still has `empty==true`, and consequently draws the prompt text when it shouldn't.

The correct implementation should be

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    versionList.setPromptText("<");
    versionList.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String version, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(version, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(version);
                setFont(Font.font(15));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @VENTO Can you post a [MCVE]? Does it happen with a standard combo box too, or just with the JFoenix version?

Comment: I tried this code with standard ComboBox and everything worked nice. I think I will ask help in JFoenix developer.

Thank toy for your help.

Comment: @VENTO That might give you more success. There's really no documentation for JFoenix from which to work for issues like this. Note that you definitely need the call to `super.updateItem(..)` though, whichever combo box you use.